# django join-like expansion of queryset

Tags: python, django, join, django-queryset

I have a list of `Person`s each which have multiple fields that I usually filter what's upon, using the object_list generic view.   Each person can have multiple `Comment`s attached to them, each with a datetime and a text string.  What I ultimately want to do is have the option to filter comments based on dates.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    ## has ~30 other fields, usually filtered on as well

class Comment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    comment = models.TextField("Comment Text", max_length=1023)
```

What I want to do is get a queryset like

```
Person.objects.filter(comment__date__gt=date(2011,1,1)).order_by('comment__date')
```

send that queryset to object_list and be able to only see the comments ordered by date with only so many objects on a page.

E.g., if "Person A" has comments 12/12/2010, 1/2/2011, 1/5/2011, "Person B" has no comments, and person C has a comment on 1/3/2010, I would see:

```
"Person A",   1/2  - comment
"Person C",   1/3  - comment
"Person A",   1/5  - comment
```

I would strongly prefer not to have to switch to filtering based on `Comments.objects.filter()`, as that would make me have to largely repeat large sections of code in the both the view and template.

Right now if I tried executing the following command, I will get a queryset returning (PersonA, PersonC, PersonA), but if I try rendering that in a template each persons comment_set will contain all their comments even if they aren't in the date range.

Ideally there would be some sort of functionality where I could expand out a `Person` queryset's `comment_set` into a larger queryset that can be sorted and ordered based on the comment and put into a object_list generic view.  This normally is fairly simple to do in SQL with a JOIN, but I don't want to abandon the ORM, which I use everywhere else.

---

OK, my solution was basically just Comments.objects.filter(); split the template into a separate file that is included in the appropriate fashion, apply extra context boolean (if comment_date_filter, apply an appropriate prefix string before all person references in the view (that's either '', or 'person__'):

```
{% if comment_date_filter %}
   {% for obj in object_list %}
      {% with obj.person as p %}
        {% include "object_list_row.html" %}
      {% endwith %}
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   {% for obj in object_list %}
      {% with obj as p %}
        {% include "object_list_row.html" %}
      {% endwith %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other option you have is to pull all objects out as `(Person, Date, Comment)` tuples and sort them in Python.

However, I don't know what your reason for not wanting to use Comment.objects.filter().  This is likely going to be fairly fast, especially if your date field is indexed.

Comment: It's mostly just doubling the amount of code in the view and the template and trying to keep things DRY, and expecting there to be a simple solution that I'm just overlooking allowing me to implement the join.  Django lets me order the Physicians based on comment dates (with repeats), but won't let me see the comments that it did the sorting based on?  That seems odd to me.  The reason I don't want to filter from Comment is that my template and view are both a couple 100 lines and do fancy things that I don't want to have to implement in two separate ways.

Comment: I believe you original query is off, `Person.objects.filter(comment__date__gt=date(2011,1,1)).order_by('comment__date')`

If my understanding is correct on the SQL this will generate, basic this is going to order people by their first comment.

What is different about
comment_date_filter and not comment_date_filter.  Why is filtering different
than not filtering?


What I mean is, why not just do this in the view:
`if filtered: objects = Comments.filter(...).order_by(...) else: objects = Comments.order_by(...)`

Comment: Also have a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#values